# Total catastrophic failure, or should a GM ever allow re-rolls and do-overs?

Tags: gm-techniques

It's a critical moment in the game at the end of a marathon session, everyone is on the edge of their seats, and the player rolls... a 1. Evil bad guy wins, party dies, game over. As a GM, what should you do? Probably don't structure your game to hinge on the result of a single roll, right? Well what if it was an improbable-but-possible series of bad rolls?

Should you ever let people re-roll after failing? I'm thinking no, otherwise everybody will want to re-roll after every bad outcome.

What about letting the party start over from when they first entered the room? Just for the sake of convenience and without any sort of time reversal game mechanic.

Comment: @ruffdove [Please don't answer in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/14878).

Comment: The system you're playing might have rules for this. If we don't know the system, we can't know. What system are you using?

Comment: I think this question should remain closed for the time being since we really need to know the system we are using in order to answer usefully (see the answer below that has to spend 1/3 of their answer saying what systems their answer *isn't* for and still having to make an assumption to answer (and if their assumption is wrong, their answer is less useful to you)). Let us know the system and we should be able to reopen it!

Comment: @RichardC [Please don't answer in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/14878).

Answer (score 5):

### All possible outcomes are possible. Don't make an outcome possible unless you're willing for it to be possible.

Otherwise, you're playing a game you do not control, and you may be in for a bad surprise.

The entire point of turning to dice or cards or stones from a bag or any randomizer at all is that, as the person who's running the opposition to the PCs, it's going to look and feel awfully, awfully fake if you also just stand there and decide whether or not the PCs fail at everything and what it costs them. But the price of disclaiming decision-making like this is that everybody who looks at the randomizer is going to have to live with its outcome.

What are you going to do, when suddenly in this moment of glory you can't live with the outcome? Tear down the curtain, guide everything into place with a hand that's always been there, reveal that you were on the PCs' side all along?

Yes, from a certain point of view, you have been on the PCs' side all along. You're not playing this game to laugh at your players and make them miserable, right? You're there so that everyone can have fun together. But part of that fun is that you get to pretend you're not, and I can't think of many well-intentioned things that would ruin that ability to pretend more than stepping in at a dramatic moment to save the day.

#### Ways To Preemptively Make Things Impossible

Here are some alternatives to just stepping in and declaring that the bad guys don't win after all.

**Let the PCs pay a price to succeed.** This is more often an option and sometimes a game mechanic in games which operate in story-scoped rather than task-scoped resolution, where the randomizer is not consulted to see whether a particular action succeeds or fails, but how well an action turns out in the story. Because there's usually some give room on what exactly counts as a failure, you can say that failing to snatch the Negaton Crystal from Umbra, lord of the Shade Wraiths, in time means that you snatch it after it's powered on and the negaton rays have taken out your shield and most of your armor and hit points. It's often possible to sneak this mechanic into systems with a task-scoped resolution, but it's easiest to do it outside the more structured elements of them, which usually include the tactical combat.

**Give your opposition something to want that isn't killing the PCs. They pursue that instead of annihilation when given the choice.** This, of course, falls apart in cases like the one we have here, where Umbra, lord of the Shade Wraiths, is dead-set on eliminating all life and has the means to do so.

**Or does it?** If you're really having trouble juxtaposing "the PCs aren't ready to die yet" with "Umbra, lord of the Shade Wraiths, will annihilate all life", then consider this - there's no guarantee that powering up the Negaton Crystal actually will annihilate all life, here and now. Maybe that is true, but the PCs show up too early and powering up the Negaton Crystal is just there to occupy the PCs so Umbra can escape and plan more carefully for next time. Or maybe, just right now, Umbra finds out there's something they missed - a stellar conjunction, a ritual ingredient, a planar alignment - and curses loudly to the heavens and also the PCs, then attempts to escape with or without the Negaton Crystal and now the PCs know something about what's going to happen next.

Answer (score 2):

In games I run, there have been a couple of times when the party all got killed and I said: "okay, we're going to do that fight over", and the group seemed fine with it.  (Certainly they were more fine with it than if I'd let them all die!)

In one game, I just told them straight-up that they got one do-over for this campaign, and they could use it whenever they wanted.  It made them more willing to take risks, but they never actually needed to use it.

I don't think I would ever allow a reroll.  I might say: "well, that was a bad roll, but the thing you were trying to do was actually really easy, so you succeed anyway."

Answer (score 2):

### Should a GM ever allow re-rolls and do-overs?

**Of course, they should.**

Ever is a very long time. I mean, for a start it includes everything that has or ever will happen and to limit a GM to one and only one particular outcome over that period seems to be a trifle restrictive don't you think?

### Scoping your question

While you don't specify a RPG system, you have made a number of assumptions:

1. There's a GM - not all systems have this.
2. The rules allow the GM to overrule outcomes - not all systems do.
3. The system doesn't have a system for allowing player-initiated "do-overs" - some do.
4. The players can fail - some RPG systems simply do not accommodate TPF (Total Player Failure).
5. You roll dice - again, some RPGs don't use dice and some don't use random outcomes at all. Arguably, the latter are storytelling games rather than role-playing games.
6. The dice have numbers - some RPG dice don't (e.g. FFG Star Wars).
7. 1s are bad - in some RPGs 1s are good.

So depending on the system, the question may not arise at all or, if it does, the system may contain ways of resolving it.

However, it *seems* that you are contemplating a system like Dungeons & Dragons where players roll dice and the result of that dice roll can lead to success or failure and failure can be total and the GM has authority to "nope" certain outcomes. I can work with that.

### It's a social contract thing

What is acceptable play depends on the particular group.

For some, the dice fall where they may and there is no joy in victory if there isn't a risk of defeat. This is the wanker-fanatic end of the scale.

For others, death and/or failure should never happen and everything should be sunshine and lollipops. This is the spoiled-toddler end of the scale.

In between is where most groups live and where each draws the line is a matter for them. They may know where the line is beforehand or work it out afterwards.

**There is no one true way.** Except that: "there is no one true way" is the one true way.

### Your sub-questions

> As a GM, what should you do?

For "should" see above.

For what I usually do (also, see above): The players lose. They made their choices, left things to chance and the lost. To deny them the right to lose is to take away their agency and that is the one thing I try very hard to avoid.

What happens next depends on a number of factors.

For example, last Thursday, the wizard died - a zombie ate him while everyone else was busy. It was a tough fight but everyone knew the wizard had failed two death saving throws (this was D&D 5e) and they all chose not to give him any healing. Their choice, their outcome - that's agency. Everyone was ok with this, including the wizard's player. However, after the session, I had an idea about how a resurrected wizard could be used to further the story albeit with a very strong chance that the wizard would die again later. So I put this (in general terms) to the wizard's player and that's what we are going to do.

> Probably don't structure your game to hinge on the result of a single roll, right?

Probably.

Still: "[The best laid schemes o' mice an' men  Gang aft a-gley.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_a_Mouse)" Or, in the modern vernacular: [Shit happens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shit_happens).

> Well what if it was an improbable-but-possible series of bad rolls?

[Shit happens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shit_happens).

Look, the player's decided to do whatever risky thing it was that required the dice roll. [You pays your money and you takes your chances](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/You+pays+your+money). They had other options, they could have hedged their bets but once you start to swing on the chandelier ...

Who are you to invalidate their choices? If you want to do that then don't roll dice.

> Should you ever let people re-roll after failing? I'm thinking no, otherwise everybody will want to re-roll after every bad outcome.

Asked and answered.

Anyway, everyone *does* want a reroll after a bad outcome - whether they get one or not is another matter.

> What about letting the party start over from when they first entered the room?

If you like.